# popup window in android

Tags: android-widget

how can i create the popupwindow with videoview in android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use an activity with popup style and show the VideoView in this Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".DetailDialog" android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomDialog"></activity>

<style name="Theme.CustomDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>      
</style>
```